# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'node_modules/stompjs/lib'

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, next.js

Got an issue where a stompJS-lib was not found, upon which I got the following error message:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/../../../.../../../angular-app/node_modules/stompjs/lib'
```

Comment: If you 're using VS Code, sometimes it will automatically add imports at the top of your JS file while you're typing code. If you're getting tons of "XXX not found" all of sudden, make sure you don't have any undesired imports

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The following command (which installs the missing dependencies):

```
 npm i net -S
```

This does not install random packages as assumed below. If you want the frontend to have some level of non-authoritative processing to be done on the client-side of those required dependencies, then this is the option to consider.

Comment: @alextes, do you have any other solution? Please suggest I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to run code that needs to run on Node in some runtime that isn't Node, like the browser: figure out what code is requiring net. Check the error for this. Replace that code with something that doesn't.

Comment: The correct one is "net": require.resolve ("net-browserify"). You must install 'net-browserify' and not 'net', in my answer you have most of them.

Comment: If you are using next js make sure you checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73226905/498463

Comment: This is helping run the application successfully. but it is not loading the home page(index.html).

Answer (score 37):

To avoid installing random packages, you could add this into your Webpack configuration.

```json
node: {
  net: 'empty',
},
```

The issue is caused by expecting the **net** package which is a package from Node.JS and does not exist in the browser.

If you want more information and explanations you can find it [here](https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/issues/119).

Answer (score 24):

To expand a bit on [Arthur Costa answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557439/2557263), if you're using NextJS, you can add a configuration in your configuration file to prevent this issue for specific imports.

Add those lines in a file named `next.config.js` in your root project folder:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        if (!isServer) {
            config.node = {
                net: 'empty'
            };
        }

        return config;
    }
}
```

In case the problem appears with other built-in modules, you can add those alongside `net` too.

Source: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7755#issuecomment-508633125

Comment: My issue was also on a Next.Js app, and my solution was to move the code to the API layer of Next.Js (e.g. `/pages/api/my-endpoint-service.ts`) and treat it like a proxy API. It comes with the benefit of the API calls I have being much more secure as well, because then you can't see the API URLs or API keys in the browser.

Comment: @BradGreens do you mind adding that as an alternative solution to this question?

Comment: Thank you. And you might add to those who are new with NextJs.. That they need to restart their app whenever they edit their configuration.

Comment: webpack5: 

webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.fallback = {
        net: false
      }
    }

Answer (score 21):

Referencing [this answer by Flavio Copes](https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-fix-module-not-found/):

> The problem is this: Next.js is trying to run backend code in the frontend.

Comment: Thanks! so much time wasted installing net or adding the exception in webpack config -_-

Comment: Very welcome @AndrésFernández, we've all been there

Answer (score 15):

webpack v5 (add to webpack.config.js in module.exports):

```
resolve: {
    fallback: {
        net: false
    }
},
```

Answer (score 8):

**If you are using a framework like Next.js**, similar error occurs when some server side code is exposed on the client side. Some dependencies are just part of Node.js. You should not run code like `npm install net` in your repo. It does not solve the problem.

You need to separate the server side and the client side code into 2 different files most of the time.

At the top of the the server side code file, add `'use server'` to avoid accidentally import this to a client side code file.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Laravel, do this:

1. Install:

   npm install util browserify-fs tls-browserify net-browserify stream-http https-browserify path-browserify crypto-browserify stream-browserify browserify-zlib os-browserify
2. Include this in Webpack.mix.js:

   mix.webpackConfig({
   resolve: {
   fallback: {
   "child_process": 'empty',
   "fs": require.resolve("browserify-fs"),
   "util": require.resolve("util"),
   "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
   "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
   "tls": require.resolve("tls-browserify"),
   "net": require.resolve("net-browserify"),
   "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
   "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
   "os": require.resolve("os-browserify"),
   "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
   "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib")
   }
   }
   });

If you don't use Laravel, include this in: Webpack.config.js or in your Webpack configuration file.

```
resolve: {
    fallback: {
        "child_process": 'empty', 
        "fs": require.resolve("browserify-fs"), 
        "util": require.resolve("util"), 
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
        "tls": require.resolve("tls-browserify"),
        "net": require.resolve("net-browserify"),
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"), 
        "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        "os": require.resolve("os-browserify"), 
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib")
    }
}
```

**Why that?**

Don't be mad at him, all he wants to know is how to deal with it, you need to indicate the respective module or set it to 'false'.

If you understand that this does not resolve, you can roll back the installations:

```
npm remove util browserify-fs tls-browserify net-browserify stream-http https-browserify path-browserify crypto-browserify stream-browserify browserify-zlib os-browserify
```

Alternative

```
resolve: {
    fallback: {
        "child_process": false, 
        "process":  false, 
        "fs": false, 
        "util": false, 
        "http": false,
        "https": false,
        "tls": false,
        "net": false,
        "crypto": false, 
        "path": false,
        "os": false, 
        "stream": false,
        "zlib": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Net` is part of NodeJS, so it doesn't exist in the browser.
https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net

Better update your Webpack configuration with

```
node: {
  net: 'empty',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on existing answers, and in particular for `stompjs`, if you only need it in a browser environment, then you can use the base `stomp.js` - it'll run just fine in-browser. It is located in `/node_modules/stompjs/lib/stomp.js`.

So, adding this alias to your webpack config would solve it, without needing to blacklist a specific node dependency.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'stompjs': __dirname + '/node_modules' + '/stompjs/lib/stomp.js',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the direct answer to the original question but for those who came here with similar problem from search and are packing server-side (or userland) apps that are running with Node. The correct solution is to use Node target parameter:

```
  -t, --target <value...>                Sets the build target e.g. node.
```

Answer (score -3):

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@google/maps/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\.....\...\node_modules\@google\maps\node_modules\https-proxy-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@google/maps/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\...\....\node_modules\@google\maps\node_modules\https-proxy-agent'
```

This is resolved by installing:
npm i tls -S 
and then install
npm i net -S