# Failed attempt at using StockX API in Webpack 5

Tags: webpack, polyfills, webpack-5

I am trying to use [stockx-api](https://github.com/matthew1232/stockx-api) for my development, when building a project with Webpack 5 - I get a lot of errors about polyfills like this:

[image]

I tried to follow the instructions, installed packages manually, and also used **resolve.fallback**, there are fewer errors, but many of them do not disappear (tls, http2, net and more) like this:

[image]

Please help if anyone faced this problem in the new version of Webpack
https://github.com/neveleneves/WishLoot

Comment: Thanks for posting your first question but next time please first use the search on the site for similar questions cause like I mention in my answer this is a common question and answered many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error has nothing todo anymore with WebPack 5. This **Module not found: error: Can't resolve 'net' in ....** is because **net** is a node module and doesn't exist in the browser. But this issue is already answered many times here on the site so follow the links below.

[Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275069/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-net-in-node-modules-stompjs-lib)

[GitHub link with explanation why the error occurs and how to solve](https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/665)

[GitHub link with more comments and solutions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827)